# Select MF (Master-File) - Read EEPROM of a javacard

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

I have two different javacard with below ATRs :

1. `3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 12 00 90 00`
2. `3b 7F 94 00 00 80 31 80 65 B0 85 02 02 ED 12 0F FF 82 90 00`

Let assume that I want to Select MF.As far as I know, and mentioned in ISO 7815-4 , we can select Master File with `00 A4 00 00` or `00 A4 00 00 02 3F 00`.

[image]

---

But when I send select MF command for the first card I receive `6A86`[**Incorrect parameters P1-P2**].

**Q1 : Does this mean MY card is not compliant with ISO-7816?! If no, what's is the reason of this error?**
[image]

And for the second card when I send *SELECT MASTER FILE* command and then *GET RESPONSE*
command (`00 CO OO OO 12`), I receive the below output.

**Q2 : What kind of information I can gain of this outut?**
[image]

**Q3 : If I don't know my card file's IDs, Can I gain them with a brute brute-force on P1-P2=0000 to P1-P2=FFFF? I mean may this brute-force make my card lock?**

**Q4 : If I know only authentication keys of my card and nothin else, is there any way to read whole the EEPROM? if yes, how?**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1: Your card is partially ISO 7816 compliant (like most cards out there). It will - in all likelyhood - not support SELECT MF out of the box. If required, you can make your Applet "default selected" (during INSTALL for INSTALL) - meaning that the Applet becomes selected directly after the ATR - and implement the behavior yourself.

A2: SELECT will return FCI/FCP (file control information, file control parameters) information if P2 is set to `00`. What is returned again depends on the card. Sometimes it is easier to only support P2 = `0C` indicating that no information is returned. This is however only available as ISO CASE 3 command, meaning that only command data is supplied (no Le byte(s)). So the 4 byte SELECT MF won't work.

A3: Yes, you can. Reading out information or selecting files does not burn through EEPROM or flash if the card is programmed correctly. Bar a EF.ATR now and then, not much files should be present on a pristine Java Card without installed Applets or native applications though. Only do this for testing purposes though, selecting all possible files during a normal read is not efficient (and some EEPROM / flash read/writes may be required for security purposes, although the OS developer should be aware of this).

A4: No, you require full card access to do that. This functionality is usually preserved to manufacturers and creators of Java Card operating systems.

Note that INITIALIZE UPDATE / EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE is specific to the Global Platform Card Manager or Security Domains. It makes no sense to perform a SELECT MF from the Card Manager.

Comment: Thank you MR.Owlstead :) God bless you.

Answer (score 4):

**Q1** : Does this mean MY card is not compliant with ISO-7816?! If no, what's is the reason of this error?

- **A1** : Your card is ISO 7816 compliant and selection methods are vendor specific see [image: table 39 in ISO 7816-4]
  it depends on vendor, you directly ask your vendor about supported selection methods.
  or you can check ATR to know which methods are supported in Table-86 in [ISO 7816-4](http://www.embedx.com/pdfs/ISO_STD_7816/info_isoiec7816-4%7Bed2.0%7Den.pdf)

**Q2 :** What kind of information I can gain of this outut?

- **A2** : This is File control parameter(FCP) which is defined in Table-12 of [ISO 7816-4](http://www.embedx.com/pdfs/ISO_STD_7816/info_isoiec7816-4%7Bed2.0%7Den.pdf) see [image]
  it is 85 in your case.

**Q3** : If I don't know my card file's IDs, Can I gain them with a brute brute-force on P1-P2=0000 to P1-P2=FFFF? I mean may this brute-force make my card lock?

- **A3** : i will not suggest this, you can simply ask your vendor about file structure present in your card, using brute-force will also decrease endurance of your card.

**Q4** : If I know only authentication keys of my card and nothin else, is there any way to read whole the EEPROM? if yes, how?

- **A4** : There is no standard command to read whole EEPROM at once.

Comment: Thank you dear Sharma. Would you please tell me how I can read EEPROM? (step by step). Is this process right?  **1-** Initial Update and External Authenticate or Verifying **2-** Select MF then DF and then EF. **3-** Select READ BINARY APDU command

Comment: Yes this is the only method...but what is your objective behind this?Please let me know may be i can help.

Comment: I have no specific objective! just trying to learn something about the card and getting more and more profesional in this subject :D ! Dear Sharma, what's is the difference between READ BINARY and UPDATE BINARY and GET DATE? (Also : WRITE BINARY and PUT DATA and WRITE RECORD?) Wha't is binary and what is record? thank you :)

Comment: If you really want to learn then please start reading ISO 7816 and global platform if you face any issues then i am here :)

Comment: Sorry dear Sharma, I changed the accepted answer, because I think mr @owlstead's answer is more useful for future visitors. thank you for your answer again brother . :)

Comment: Sorry The good user but i am not satisfied with your move....i think i have given my answers with proof.(not a spoon feeding)....thanks anyways :)

Comment: You are right dear sharma. your answer satisfy me. But I think owlstead's answer is more comprehensive for future visitors. :) take it easy brother. we gather here to teach and learn not for bounties ;) . You are one of my heroes here :)